# Closing a JOptionPane Causes a Deadlock in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, deadlock

I have an application which runs OK at most sites.   But one site, which is hosting the application on a Citrix Box appears to have a deadlock problem.   I ran a profiler on the session and received a surprise.   The statement causing the deadlock appears to be a statement which closes a JOptionPane dialogue box.    Please see the enclosed display.

So I have three questions:

1. Is my interpretation correct?
2. Any idea of why this can happen.
3. What can I do in code to prevent this from occurring?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Elliott[image: Profiler display]

Comment: I may be missing something, but what makes you think this is a deadlock situation?

Comment: The machine where this process is running has 50% of the CPU being consumed.   When I snap shot the machine a few minutes later, a still see that the process is trying to dispose a window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing is not thread-safe. Perhaps your app is calling Swing GUI methods from outside of the Event Dispatch Thread.

If you can reduce this to a minimal sample that still reproduces the problem, you will either 1) find the cause yourself in the process, or otherwise 2) end up with a much greater chance of getting help from someone else.

Comment: *"minimal sample that still reproduces the problem"*  What, you mean like an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)? ;)

Comment: Yes :-). Great description btw.

Comment: Look at the display carefully.    Doesn't it look like the this is being called from within an EventDispatchThead?

Comment: @Elliot: `Window.dispose` itself is being called from the EDT, but the question still stands: Is your app calling Swing GUI methods from outside of the EDT? If it is doing so, this could be causing the deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't know, but if it is..
2. Calling GUI methods (update the GUI) off the EDT.
3. Call GUI methods on the EDT.

Comment: I vote for `1. what is Don't know, but if it is.. EventQueue#push()`